# Debugging IPython notebook when no error is thrown

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I think I'm missing some of the debug output of my IPython notebooks. I've activated the "debug" option and I'm shown stuff like

```
2015-01-28 08:52:08.894 [NotebookApp] Kernel started: d2e54c85-d386-4029-a1b1-edacba4d1dfe
WARNING: Attempting to work in a virtualenv. If you encounter problems, please install IPython inside the virtualenv.
...
2015-01-28 11:31:55.536 [NotebookApp] Saving notebook at /dev_testclass.ipynb
2015-01-28 11:32:01.960 [NotebookApp] Kernel restarted: d2e54c85-d386-4029-a1b1-edacba4d1dfe
```

in the terminal.

However I'm having a problem where the notebook doesn't work but no error is shown in the above output. I can't reproduce the problem consistently, so I'm looking for indications on how to study it.

I'm keeping the description of the problem generic on purpose. My question is not how to solve this particular problem, but rather **how to obtain all the possible error logs from IPython**, so that I can get hints and possibly file a bug.

If necessary, I can elaborate on the problem specifics.

Here's my virtualenv:

```
$ pip freeze
axeltoolspy==0.3.0                                         
backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.4.0.2                      
certifi==14.5.14                                           
easydict==1.5                                              
gevent==1.0.1                                              
greenlet==0.4.5                                            
ipython==2.3.1                                             
Jinja2==2.7.3                                              
MarkupSafe==0.23                                           
matplotlib==1.4.2                                          
mpld3==0.2                                                 
numpy==1.9.1                                               
pandas==0.15.2                                             
pyparsing==2.0.3                                           
pyreadline==2.0                                            
python-dateutil==2.4.0                                     
pytz==2014.10                                              
pyzmq==14.5.0                                              
six==1.9.0                                                 
tornado==4.0.2                                             
websocket==0.2.1                                           
websocket-client==0.23.0
```

Comment: How are you activating the debug?  At the command line, or through %log magic?

Comment: I'm using the --debug option from the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed that opening the browser's built-in dev console (F12 on Chrome) reveals some errors that are not mentioned in ipython's command-line output, i.e. websocket connection problems.  I guess that's all I can hope for.